# Sharepoint search error with www,

Tags: search, document-id

I'm having an issue with the 'www' subdomain. If I go to

> http://www.example.com/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=UY5JTSVC6DCC-1-83

I get an error

> Could not look up Document ID "UY5JTSVC6DCC-1-83
>   due to an error encountered in Microsoft Search Server.
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

However, if I go to

> http://example.com/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=UY5JTSVC6DCC-1-83

I don't have a problem.

I don't see anything helpful when I go to ULS logs. I've verified that the 'www' is included in the content source start addresses.